# Getting Permission Denied when accessing 'storage/0/emulated/download' path even if permissions are granted

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to download a file to storage/0/emulated/download. It is working fine if we grant permission using Permission.storage.request() at app launch time but if we give permission by clicking on 'Allow' by Permission.storage.request() during run time it gives a permission denied error.

Comment: It is pretty unclear about which permission you are talking. And do you mean /storage/emulated/0/Download ? If so then why not write so? Your app can just create files in that directory with the old wellknown WRITE permission. Please be clear where you have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

you should download file to your app OWN(sandbox) storage space

```
private void saveAppPrivateFils(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "2.jpg");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fail" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2359 demo had posted