# Not able to access storage in Android 12 using permission handler in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions

I'm trying to access the "/storage/emulated/0/Download" directory in Android. I'm using the permission_handler package to request this permission. I added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in AndroidManifest.xml.

The issue is that I am able to access the same path in Android 11 and earlier versions but not in Android 12. When I tried using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_DIRECTORIES in Android 12, it worked fine, but I don't want to use this permission as it is sensitive and the play store may reject this if we use this permission. I'm wondering why the same flow works fine in Android 11 but not in Android 12. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do when you speak about accessing the public Download directory?

Comment: Am trying to write a .txt file in downloads folder @blackapps

Comment: Not enough info. No idea what you tried. And no reactions here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704095/getting-permission-denied-when-accessing-storage-0-emulated-download-path-even